# Search a Map versus a List

Tags: java, performance, list, dictionary

I have a question on efficiency.

Say I have a List of a simple objects `Foo`

```
public class Foo {
    Integer id;
    List<String> data;
    ...
}
```

Now I have a list of the foo class

```
List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
```

Say I have a collection of thousands of records and I need to add them to this list but when I come across an id that has already been added to the list I need to append the foo.data list rather than add a new foo with the duplicate id.

Would it be wise to create a map for each unique foo.id I encounter like this

```
Map<Integer, Foo> uniqueFoos = new HashMap<Integer, Foo>();
```

And as I iterate over my thousands of records I simply perform a check on the map to see if the foo.id already exists

```
if(uniqueFoos.containes(record.id))
    uniqueFoos.getFoo().add(record.data)

else
    uniqueFoos.add(record.id, record)
```

And once I've added all of the records to the map I then iterate over the map and add each of the Foos to the list

```
for(Foos f: uniqueFoos)
    fooList.add(fooInMap.get(f))
```

Or should I scrap the `Map` idea all together. Would it be more efficient to iterate over the `fooList` and search for whether or not it already contains a `foo.id` that matches the record.id. Or maybe even use the `ArrayList.contains(...)` method? I feel like it would much more inefficient doing it this way versus the map way.

**Update:** Some people have mentioned using a Set as well. So would a Set be the way to go over all the other listed options?

**Note: The code I wrote here is simply pseudo code.**

Comment: Why not use a `Set`?

Comment: What are you doing with the ID value in your 'foo' object?  Can you just use the map, key on the ID, and make your value the list of strings?

Comment: @keppil I studied sets but to be honest I've never used one. I'm reading up on it now. Very interesting suggestion.

Comment: Whenever you need a collection without duplicates, you should consider using a `Set`. Just remember to override the `hashcode()` and `equals()` method with custom objects like `Foo`.

Comment: @keppil will a Set be faster than a Map?

Comment: They will have the same lookup performance when checking if an element is present (in fact, a `Set` often uses a `Map` internally).

Comment: @keppil so then it sounds like I should just use a Map then.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap is definitely a better choice. It will do lookup in O(1), whereas List is O(n).

So if you need to lookup and modify individual elements often go with HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say for sure without profiling your code. However, random accesses for hash maps take a constant amount of time (most of the times - if there are no collisions), while iterating over arrays is always linear.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use a `Map` when you have "thousands of records".

Your example `uniqueFoos.getFoo().add(record.data)` doesn't compile.
It should be `uniqueFoos.get(record.id).add(record.data)`.

To prevent double lookup in the map, your code should be:

```
Foo foo = uniqueFoos.get(record.id);
if (foo == null) // not found
    uniqueFoos.add(record.id, record);
else
    foo.add(record.data);
```